# A* admissible heuristics on a array sorting

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to solve an A* admissible heuristic for a problem like this-

> I have a array of numbers.
>
> I am only allowed to swap two adjacent numbers.
>
> I need to solve it minimum no of swaps.

Can anyone please help me to find an admissible heuristic for this problem?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good heuristic for this problem is to count the number of inversions in the array.

An inversion is a pair of indices i,j with i < j such that A[i] > A[j] (i.e. the pair is not in the right order).

There is an O(nlogn) method to compute the number of inversions via mergesort (see [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions) for a description of some methods).

This is a good heuristic because the number of inversions gives the **exact** distance to the goal.  There will always be a possible move that reduces the number of inversions by 1.  Making such moves will sort the array in the minimum number of steps.

Comment: This works, but a heuristic is pretty pointless if it takes the same amount of time as the problem you're trying to solve. You could, for instance, just take the number of incorrectly ordered adjacent pairs. This number is always smaller than (or equal to) the number of inversions, so it is also admissible.